# Why React should be in scope when writing a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

So it's pretty self-explanatory when talking about class components as they are part of the global React object, But what's the reason behind that it should be imported with every functional component?
and are bundlers taken into consideration?

I have been coding for 5 months now, so I'm sorry if the answer to my question is obvious, and thanks for your attention.

Comment: It should be imported to use the JSX

Comment: [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#react-must-be-in-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#react-must-be-in-scope):

> Since JSX compiles into calls to React.createElement, the React library must also always be in scope from your JSX code.

`React.createElement` will fail if React is not in scope.